# SubmitChanges internally adds all the fields as where clause, how to get rid of it

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, where-clause, submitchanges

I have a table in database with a primary key say `emp_pk`. Now using LINQ I am trying to perform some operations on it. When I change few properties and call,

```
context.SubmitChanges();
```

ideally the where clause should contain `where emp_pk = value`.

But when I review the query from SQL profiler, I see lot of conditions in where clause, which I believe are generated by LINQ engine. This is causing a major performance issue.

Can anyone please help me in this case to optimize the query?

Comment: This is causing a major performance issue: really?? Why?Or is the performance issue created by linq-2-sql updating a lot of records one at a time.

Comment: 10k in itsself is not a problem. The question is how many you update at a time. If you are updating large amounts of records at the same time Linq2Sql is not the best choice performancewise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because  optimistic concurrency check is enabled. You can turn it off per column by setting Update Check=never per column in the dbml designer

Comment: I am using SQLMetal to generate classes. Please let me know how I can do the same with SQLMEtal.

Comment: I saw the class generated by SQLMetal. For some of the columns this property is set, but not for all. And for the columns where this property is set, these columns are used in SET statement.